# PyInstaller alpine linux error Cannot find libc.musl-x86_64.so.1

Tags: python-3.x, docker, python-3.6, pyinstaller, alpine-linux

I am using the following Dockerfile to build my project

```
FROM alpine:3.7
WORKDIR /app/proj
COPY . /app/proj
RUN apk update && apk add build-base python3 python3-dev --no-cache bash &&  \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
    pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --no-cache-dir -e. && \
    pip3 install pyinstaller==3.5 && \
    pip3 install PyCrypto && \
    rm -rf tests instance tmp myapp.egg-info Docker && \
    pyinstaller ./myapp/cli.py  --name myapp_binary --exclude-module scripts --exclude-module tests --exclude-module docker --exclude-module build --onefile


EXPOSE 5000 3306
```

But I am getting the following error when trying to build the docker image

`4136 ERROR: Can not find libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 in path ldd (needed by /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0)`

Added

```
ln -s /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 ldd && \
ln -s /lib /lib64 && \
```

and it created the executable, but when I tried to run it, 
it throws an error in alpine linux

```
/app/proj/dist # sh ./myapp_binary 
./myapp_binary: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Did you try downloading it manually and creating a symlink? Do take a look at this https://github.com/alexander-akhmetov/python-telegram/issues/3

Comment: Yes I already have gone through his workaround and it does not work in Alpine linux

Comment: At which step are you getting this error?

Comment: @PraveenRewar if I add ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl/libc.so /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 it breaks  ln: /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1: File exists

Comment: According to this thread "I can fix it with `ln -s /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 ldd`. The binary that gets produced still doesn't run though as it tries to find some libs in /lib64. This is resolved with `ln -s /lib /lib64`" https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/48

Comment: Sorry I have gone through this as well  and posted the question after doing all the workarounds @PraveenRewar thanks

Comment: Basically the file already exists, but it's getting to find it in ldd.

Comment: Okay my bad, please edit your question mentioning what you have already tried, so that others can know :)

Comment: @PraveenRewar https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/4164/486860998

Comment: Well, that explains why it didn't work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try to add few more packages to apk add

```
apk add libstdc++ unixodbc unixodbc-dev freetds-dev
```